# SQL Injection in ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, security, activerecord

I'm trying to build a vulnerable demo application. I'm using SQLite, and I have ruby code that looks like this:

`@value = current_user.accounts.calculate(:sum, params[:column])`

And the SQL generates the following by default:

`User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT SUM("accounts"."account_value") AS sum_id FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]`

Next, I put `ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --` into the form and I get the following:

```
(0.3ms)  SELECT SUM(ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --)) AS sum_id FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
SQLite3::RangeException: bind or column index out of range: SELECT SUM(ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --)) AS sum_id FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::RangeException: bind or column index out of range: SELECT SUM(ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --)) AS sum_id FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?):
  app/controllers/instant_calculator_controller.rb:3:in `sum'
```

I think the issue is that the 'user_id' section tacked onto the end as a paramiterized query is messing this up. I tried doing something like `ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'OR user_id = ?; --` just to throw that part of the query away, but that didn't seem to help.

Does anyone have any thoughts on I could make this work? I can change the code as well as the query, but I'd prefer to change the query before changing to code to make it SQLiable.

**EDIT:**

A bit more info. If I take the SQL that is generated and just change the last user_id to '1' so it looks like `SELECT SUM(ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --) AS sum_id FROM 'accounts'  WHERE 'accounts'.'user_id' = 1` it works perfectly. I don't understand why this matters as everything after `--` should be ignored.

Comment: Try giving the table name to columns. Like `user.ssn` and `user.name`

Comment: @RubyRacer I get ` wrong number of arguments to function SUM()` for an error. This makes sense though because the SQL being constructed doesn't know about the user object and ssn or name method.

Comment: I'm quite sure that if you paste the derived statement in sqlite console, it will work, taking the problem to handling from AR...

Comment: @RubyRacer, Maybe I'm miss understanding you. Can you structure the sql how you want it and paste it in to make sure I'm not just clueless.

Comment: If you open your sqlite db with this command from console: `sqlite3 db/yourdb.sqlite3` and on the console you paste `SELECT SUM(ssn) FROM users WHERE name = 'Texas'; --)) AS sum_id FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]` and press enter, it will work. It doesn't work through Rails because ActiveRecord does something (vague, I don't know) to the query, some sort of sanitization perhaps, before sending it to the DB adapter.